# Ada sin(x) Computing with Taylor-series

Tags: ada, trigonometry

I'm an absolute beginner in Ada and I'm trying to calculate sin(x) [sin(3) now] by using Taylor-series, but I just can't get it to work.

So here is my procedure:

```
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Mat;
procedure SinKoz is
    X:Float:=3.0;
    Szamlalo:Float:=0.0;
begin
    for I in 1..100 loop
        Szamlalo := Szamlalo + ((-1.0)**I)*(X**(2.0*I+1.0))/Mat.Faktorialis(2*I+1);
    end loop;
    Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put( Szamlalo );
end SinKoz;
```

And inside Mat, here is my Faktorialis, which calculates the factorial of 2*I+1:

```
function Faktorialis( N: Float ) return Float is
      Fakt : Float := 1.0;
begin
      for I in 1..N loop
         Fakt := Fakt * I;
      end loop;
      return Fakt;
end Faktorialis;
```

When i'm trying to compile my code, this error comes up:
**exponent must be of type Natural, found type "Standard.Float"**

I hope you can help me trying to figure out what went wrong with my types!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question is : do you need to raise X to a non-integer power?

It looks to me as if you don't : in which case replace `X**(2.0*I+1.0)` with `X**(2*I+1)` and all will be well.

But if you really do (perhaps not here, but in another application) you just need to make such an operator visible : there's one for Float in the package `Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions` so precede your function with

```
with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
use Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
```

and it should work as written.
Finally, if you have created your own float type, you can instantiate the generic package `Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions` with your type as its parameter, to create a set of these functions specifically for your type.

Comment: +1: duh.  This answer is better than mine :)  I've been away from Ada for a little while.

Comment: Thank you, it is a well detailed answer!

Comment: Sometimes knowing several ways to do the job is a good thing. Ada is a very well stocked toolbox, not just a hammer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love Ada's strong typing.

Off the top of my head, I suspect your problem may be this line:

```
Szamlalo := Szamlalo + ((-1.0)**I)*(X**(2.0*I+1.0))/Mat.Faktorialis(2*I+1);
```

`2.0*I+1.0` is going to return a Float.  Not a Natural.  You could try wrapping that in `Integer()` or `Natural()` (Natural is a subtype of Integer) and see if that helps.

Comment: It was the problem, thank you! Yeah, it is really strong for my taste.